# Conditional operator cannot be used with list values using concat

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to use a concat to combine two lists of subnets

I initially tried using join on the two subnets as well which failed with error :

```
join: argument 1 should be type string, got type list in:
```

I am now trying to use concat for the same strings which when combined would result in a list which throws another error.

```
conditional operator cannot be used with list values
```

My current code is as below:

```
subnet_ids           = ["${split(",",(terraform.workspace == "dev" || terraform.workspace == "test" || terraform.workspace == "qa" || terraform.workspace == "sit") ? concat(data.terraform_remote_state.abc_subnet,data.terraform_remote_state.abc_subnet2) : concat(data.terraform_remote_state.xys_subnet,data.terraform_remote_state.xyz_subnet2))}"]
```

Update : Since there are a few subnets the right way to do this would be to perhaps use element() and then count.index which would require some complex syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Terraform 0.11 and earlier have a limitation that the conditional operator can only be used with primitive types. This limitation was addressed in Terraform 0.12, so the conditional operator can be used with all types after upgrading:

```
locals {
  has_two_subnets = terraform.workspace == "dev" || terraform.workspace == "test" || terraform.workspace == "qa" || terraform.workspace == "sit"
}

resource "example" "example" {
  subnet_ids = (
    local.has_two_subnets ?
    concat(
      data.terraform_remote_state.abc_subnet,
      data.terraform_remote_state.abc_subnet2,
    ) :
    data.terraform_remote_state.xyz_subnet2
  )
}
```

To work around this with Terraform 0.11, a common trick is to join the lists together into delimited strings and then split them again after selection:

```
locals {
  has_two_subnets = "${terraform.workspace == "dev" || terraform.workspace == "test" || terraform.workspace == "qa" || terraform.workspace == "sit"}"
}

resource "example" "example" {
  subnet_ids = "${split(" ", local.has_two_subnets ? join(" ", concat(data.terraform_remote_state.abc_subnet,data.terraform_remote_state.abc_subnet2)) : join(" ", data.terraform_remote_state.xyz_subnet2))}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this out, you have used join once and then concat but only on one subnet (?)